# Calling from another android project

Tags: java, android

I have 2 android projects, A and B. I want to call a B method from a class (no Activity) of A project.
If B project were a pure Java project written in jdk 1.6, for example, I wouldn't have any problem. But in this case it crashes.
I’ve added B project on the build path and selected at order and export.

I don't want to use jar libs, because I prefer adapt B project to my requeriments. I use this way to develop at pure Java projects and it's usefull. I make my own libraries along the way.

I put you code here:

**Class A:**

```
package com.example.a;

import com.example.b.ClassNoActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ClassNoActivity.showMessage(); // Here crashes
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Class B:**

```
package com.example.b;

public class ClassNoActivity {

    public static void showMessage() {
        System.out.println("I'm a message.");
    }

}
```

**LogCat:**

```
10-28 08:31:40.926: W/dalvikvm(3466): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4617: Lcom/example/b/ClassNoActivity;.showMessage ()V
10-28 08:31:41.156: W/dalvikvm(3466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db41f8)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.b.ClassNoActivity
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at com.example.a.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4636)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
10-28 08:31:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(3466):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you add B as a library reference in project properties, under "Android"?

Comment: Have you tried adding project B as 'Library project'?

Comment: in src folder add this  com.example.b as new package

Comment: Thanks so much! The solution was as simple as mark project as a library and then references it on the A project (Properties/Android).
Cool!

Comment: Take care about 1.7 compiler Java in old SDK android projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @desert say's try adding project B as a library project in project A, and you can import the package as you wish...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is create a service in project B whose task would be to invoke the method that you want to invoke. Now from project A, you can start this service and can get the desired result.

Comment: I've never used services, but I suppose it's not very difficult. Will I have to write anything on the A project manifest?

Comment: nope.. just add it to the manifest on project B as it belongs to project B.. and also while at it.. declare an `intent-filter` in that service so that you may not need to hard-code the service name in your intent object. You can pass the same URI that you declared in the `intent-filter` tag to invoke the service. Its quite easy than it sounds plus you'll be learning a basic component in Android that is used extensively. 

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. The solution was as simple as mark project as a library and then references it on the A project (Properties/Android).